# Scope problems(?) with PlatformIO

Tags: c++, arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266, platformio

I have been looking at other development platforms for working on Atmel (Arduino/ATTiny) and Espressif (ESP8266) based devices. Most recently, I installed PlatformIO. But I'm having trouble with what appears to be recognition of global scope. Not sure...

I have a header file that includes a typedef for a configuration struct:

```
typedef struct {
        char idPrefix[8];
        char defPass[16];
        char targetSSID[32];
        char targetPass[64];
        uint8_t beepInRange;
        uint8_t beepOutofRange;
} devConfig;
```

I want to assign a config variable in my ino file:

```
devConfig myConfig;
```

but when i try to access it in my setup or loop, e.g.:

```
void setup() {
  strncpy(myConfig.defPass, "somepass", 16);
}
```

It spits out the *"error: 'myConfig' was not declared in this scope"* when I try to platform run

Does this thing not support global variables in the same way as arduino? What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you paste the whole struct into your file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must have forgotten to add `#include "Arduino.h"` header file in the main code. Also, do note that Platform IO compiles cpp files not ino file.

**main.cpp**

```
// Without Arduino.h this code will not compile
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "demo.h"

devConfig myConfig;

void setup() {
  strncpy(myConfig.defPass, "somepass", 16);
}

void loop() {

}
```

**demo.h**

```
typedef struct {
        char idPrefix[8];
        char defPass[16];
        char targetSSID[32];
        char targetPass[64];
        uint8_t beepInRange;
        uint8_t beepOutofRange;
} devConfig;
```

Comment: Yeah, that's basically the structure I had and you may well be right. I had Arduino.h included in a class file I was playing with also, but didn't stop to think that I'd need to manually include it in the main ino file. I'll try that later tonight. Thanks.

Comment: If this clarifies your question, accept and upvote the answer so that other people can find it useful.

Comment: I had to test it first! lol
========================= [SUCCESS] Took 21.32 seconds =========================
thank you